# how to change the popup content based on the current url extension page action

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

am new in creating chrome extensions, I'm developing an extension page action it works in certain urls, I would like to put different text in the popup for each url,  i can do it? please help me.

My background.js is thus

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

  if (~tab.url.indexOf('url1.com.br')) {
  chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
 }

 if (~tab.url.indexOf('url2.com.br')) {
 chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
}

});
```

Comment: I couldn't understand the question. Correct me please. Your extension is using page action. Page action icon is shown in specific urls. When user clicks on the page action icon, a popop opens. Finally, you want different texts for different url in that popup ? Is that what you want here?

Comment: yes is exactly that, could help me?

Answer (score 2):

OK. First of all, **to show page_action icon** on specific URLs you can use **declarative content**.

```
// When the extension is installed or upgraded ...
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  // Replace all rules ...
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    // With a new rule ...
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
      {
        // That fires when a page's on a specific URL
        conditions: [
          new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
            pageUrl: { urlContains: 'url1.com.br' },
          }),
          new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
            pageUrl: { urlContains: 'url2.com.br' }
          })
        ],
        // And shows the extension's page action.
        actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
      }
    ]);
  });
});
```

Don't forget adding a **permission for declarative content** in **manifest.json**. Another thing is different texts for different urls.

popup.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'currentWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
  var dynamicText = "You are here;"+ tabs[0].url;
  document.getElementById("textbox").value = dynamicText ;
});
```

This sample gets the currentWindow's URL and insert it into the element that has textbox id. I hope samples are enough to solve the problem.